How to forward messages with media using a Telegram bot?
Due to a lack of knowledge, I encountered an issue on the TelebotCreator website. I created a simple bot, but I can’t forward messages if they contain one or more photos or videos. Messages without media are forwarded without any problems, but when media is attached, the message fails to send.
I know there are experienced people here; could you help me solve this problem?
    GROUP_ID = "*******"
if msg:
bot.forwardMessage(GROUP_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)

P.S. Guys, please, no insults...

You can send message with media like .gif file.
          await bot.sendAnimation(chatId, defaultIMG.file_id, {
            duration: defaultIMG.duration || 2,
            width: defaultIMG.width || 640,
            height: defaultIMG.height || 640,
            thumb: defaultIMG.thumb.file_id,
            caption: strBotDM, // Add the caption here
            parse_mode: "HTML",
          });

Please check this github repo.
https://github.com/Any-bot/D2T-msg-forward
Also https://dev.to/plzbugmenot/building-a-discord-to-telegram-token-address-forwarder-8m
I wanna hear from you.
Thank you.

Hello, I tried running your version, but it did not produce any results, and I couldn't send the photos.

If you want to send photo, you can use this codebase.
api.sendPhoto({
    chat_id : message.chat.id,
    caption: 'This is my test image',
    photo: 'image.jpeg'//replace your image url here
})
.then(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});


If you want to send photo, you can use this codebase.
api.sendPhoto({
    chat_id : message.chat.id,
    caption: 'This is my test image',
    photo: 'image.jpeg'//replace your image url here
})
.then(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});

Also here.
   _img = url of Image;
    // console.log("photo", _img);

    await bot.sendPhoto(channel, _img, {
      caption: Content,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
    });

